# 'fraud' can refer to a person, what word can we use for a thing?

Tags: word-choice

We can say: "that man is a fraud", what word can I use in "the theory of relativity is a...*fraud*"?

I am looking for a word that carries the same severe negative connotation

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a noun? The adjective *fraudulent* could be applied, though it's not necessarily the best fit. Because the theory in and of itself cannot actually act in a deceitful manner, it cannot act deceitfully. You could say that a given theory "is bunk," [reference for that word here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/bunk).

Comment: I gave an example: "relativity,," the word must fit. 'hoax' is a deliberate prank, 'swindle' regards money etc,

Comment: _Fraud_ itself is perfectly acceptable. It can be used for both the fraudulent act and the person who commits the act.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hoax** for frauds conceptual, **swindle** for frauds practical. A peek into a thesaurus might reveal things like **hoodwinking** too...

Answer (score 0):

> the theory of relativity is a **fallacy**

As defined by [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fallacy)

> **fal·la·cy**  (fl-s)
>   *n*. *pl*. **fal·la·cies**
>    1. A false notion.
>    2. A statement or an argument based on a false or invalid inference.
>    3. Incorrectness of reasoning or belief; erroneousness.
>    4. The quality of being deceptive.

> *To one imbued from infancy with the fascinating **fallacy** that all men
>   are born equal, unquestioning submission to authority is not easily
>   mastered, and the American volunteer soldier in his "green and salad
>   days" is among the worst known.*

possible synonyms include: *misconception, misbelief, delusion, misinterpretation misconstruction, untruth, myth*.

Comment: Fallacy doesn't carry the unethical slant as fraud does.